# Simple ball animation in android

Tags: android

i have a simple ball view which i want to animate ( bounce ). I have this method in my activity:

```
public void beginAnimation() {
    boolean boola = true;
    while(boola) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            ball.setY(ball.getY() + 10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ball.getY() > 200) {
            boola = false;
        }
    }

}
```

When I call it from onCreate(), the animation is not being shown up, it seems that I need a special thread for this, but since threads cannot modify UI elements, how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Never call `Thread.sleep(10)` from the main thread. It will block user input. I'm surprised it doesn't throw an exception. You could use handler.postDelayed to run code at a later time on the main thread, but Marcin's answer is better so I won't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override onDraw(Canvas c) method of your View and call your beginAnimation() from there, not from Activity. Please check this example http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Short question, as this is also not clear to me :
If I create a rectangle, with xPos = 50 & yPos = 50, after I get the positions in the activity will i get these numbers, or I will get 0 ? I am wondering how can I connect this movement method from the view with a later movement triggered from a touch.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shwetachauhan.animationstarter.MainActivity">


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@mipmap/ball"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="87dp" />
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of how this solves the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "AnimationStarter";
Button bounceBtn;
ImageView imagView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialization();
    setListener();
}

private void initialization() {
    bounceBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    imagView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

private void setListener() {
    bounceBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    imagView.clearAnimation();
    //  imagView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                TranslateAnimation transAnim=new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,-getDisplayHeight()/2);

TranslateAnimation transAnim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -getDisplayHeight() / 2, 0);
transAnim.setStartOffset(500);
transAnim.setDuration(3000);
transAnim.setFillAfter(true);
transAnim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
transAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting button dropdown animation");
    }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Log.i(TAG,
                    "Ending button dropdown animation. Clearing animation and setting layout");
            imagView.clearAnimation();
            final int left = imagView.getLeft();
            final int top = imagView.getTop();
            final int right = imagView.getRight();
            final int bottom = imagView.getBottom();
            imagView.layout(left, top, right, bottom);


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
    imagView.startAnimation(transAnim);
}

private int getDisplayHeight() {
    return this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}

}
```